# Генератор случайных чисел Python

Tags: python, django

Как мне сделать функцию generator_unique_number в диапазоне не повторяющихся случайных чисел
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужен рандомный уникальный идентификатор, то лучше использовать UUID:

```
order_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
```

Подробнее можете изучить здесь: https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

```
import uuid

print(uuid.uuid4()) # 4852c16f-3b9c-4102-9d3e-ffe1a68e2a35
```

Answer (score 1):

Получить неповторяющиеся случайные значения в заданном диапазоне в зависимости от контекста можно разными способами. Наиболее просто это можно сделать, например, так:

```
random.sample(range(10000), 900) # Получаем 900 случайных чисел 
                                 # в диапазоне 0-9999 без повторения
```

или так:

```
x=list(range(10000))  # Получаем 10000 случайных чисел в диапазоне 0-9999
random.shuffle(x)     # без повторения
```

Comment: Если автору вопроса необходим идентификатор для order_id с случайными цифрами, то данная реализация может вызвать ошибку. Присутствует все же вероятность, что попадется повторяющееся число (в текущем случае идентификатор). В итоге при сохранении в БД будет вызвано исключение. После генерации придется дополнительно проверять на наличие записи с полученным ID и если такая запись существует, то повторять процесс с генерации числа. Если я верно понял задачу, то лучшим решением будет использовать uuid.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вам нужен [линейный конгруэнтный генератор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4). Его реализацию на нужном языке легко найдете в просторах сети Интернет, например вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140589/linear-congruential-generator-in-python).

Только вопрос чем Вам модуль `random` не устроил?

Comment: как делает уникальность random же не гарантируют уникальность?

Comment: @muhtorYusufjanov, обычная нумерация чем вам не уникальность?

Comment: @muhtorYusufjanov согласен, но какова вероятность повтора числе с использованием функции random?